# How do add Styles to JCE editor in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: editor, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5 with the JCE editor. I want to add my own styles but the problem is they don't appear in the Styles selection of the editor. I have the JCE configuration pointing to the editor.css, and while it does recognize the other classes in the editor.css file it doesn't recognize the ones I've added. I've cleared cache in the browser and cleared cache in Joomla, have logged out and back in, and they still don't appear.

What am I doing wrong that these Styles don't appear? Does JCE read them directly from the editor.css files each time the page loads or does it store them in some intermediary place or even in a MySQL table?

I was looking at this article:
http://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/tutorials/editor/item/create-a-custom-editor-stylesheet

I'm not clear on this, the class has to be present in the editor.css AND the template.css, not just the editor.css? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JCE might cache the contents of the custom CSS file, but you should be able to see any changes you make to editor.css in your styles drop down. The file you point JCE to use for custom styles only allows you to see them in the style drop down. In order for the styles to work on the site, you have to either a) load the same file in to your template so the styles are available or b) add the styles to your template.css or other css file that is being loaded by your template.